# OpenXava Exception: Seems that <module> is not an EJB3 Entity nor transient model class

Tags: openxava

I am trying to deploy an OpenXava project from a war on my local tomcat. It was earlier working on a different host, so don't think there is any issue with the code. But when I'm hitting the URL, I'm getting the mentioned error. Here is the stack trace:

```
type Exception report

message org.openxava.util.XavaException: Seems that Feature is not an EJB3 Entity nor transient model class

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.openxava.util.XavaException: Seems that Feature is not an EJB3 Entity nor transient model class
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:549)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:470)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.openxava.web.servlets.ModuleServlet.doGet(ModuleServlet.java:24)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
root cause

org.openxava.util.XavaException: Seems that Feature is not an EJB3 Entity nor transient model class
    org.openxava.annotations.parse.AnnotatedClassParser.getClassNameFor(AnnotatedClassParser.java:2485)
    org.openxava.annotations.parse.AnnotatedClassParser.parse(AnnotatedClassParser.java:180)
    org.openxava.component.ComponentParser.parseAnnotatedClass(ComponentParser.java:47)
    org.openxava.component.ComponentParser.parse(ComponentParser.java:36)
    org.openxava.component.MetaComponent.get(MetaComponent.java:60)
    org.openxava.component.MetaComponent.exists(MetaComponent.java:75)
    org.openxava.application.meta.MetaApplication.existsModel(MetaApplication.java:151)
    org.openxava.application.meta.MetaApplication.getMetaModule(MetaApplication.java:140)
    org.openxava.controller.ModuleManager.getMetaModule(ModuleManager.java:1022)
    org.openxava.controller.ModuleManager.setupModuleControllers(ModuleManager.java:230)
    org.openxava.controller.ModuleManager.setModuleName(ModuleManager.java:995)
    org.apache.jsp.xava.module_jsp._jspService(module_jsp.java:173)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    org.openxava.web.servlets.ModuleServlet.doGet(ModuleServlet.java:24)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

The project and module names are both in correct casing.
I want to know what could be the possible causes for this exception.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly it cannot connect to dabase, maybe the datasource is not defined, or incorrectly defined, or the JDBC driver is not in the Tomcat, etc. In the traces in the Tomcat log you'll find the root cause of the problem.